# Содержимое переменной отображается в разных местах

Tags: php, html, html5

Есть переменная

```
$content="texttexttexttexttext".$my_content->show_vars();
```

которая заменяет собой тег {#content} расположенный внутри div блока для вывода контента.

```html
    <div class="lg-7">{#content}</div>
```

Первая часть "texttexttexttexttext" отображается на странице внутри этого блока, как и должно быть, а остальная часть $my_content->show_vars() отдельно, вне этого блока, в левом верхнем углу. Переменная $my_content экземпляр класса content_

```
class content_{

    function show_vars(){
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_GET);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

}
```

Текст через переменную отображается нормально, а $my_content->show_vars() никак не хочет в div'e отображаться ни вместе с текстом ни отдельно. Почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что ты конкатенируешь функцию, которая не возвращает, а печатает.

попробуй

```
    function show_vars(){
        $str = "<pre>"; 
        foreach($_GET as $key=>$val) {
            $str.="$key => $val \n";   
        }
        $str.="</pre>";
        return $str;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, так работает. А через var_dump значит нельзя вывести?

Comment: Есть функция называется var_export, она может возвращать результат, а не печатать его